# Possible to run a program on my desktop whereas it is located on remote server?

Tags: remoteapp, remote-access

I know that it is possible to run programs on terminal with ssh programs but is it also viable to run a program on my desktop with its GUI. For example suppose I installed Matlab on a remote machine and run it on my computer. If it is feasible, what are the methods that can be applied?

I did what the below one says but now I am getting `No X11 DISPLAY variable was set` error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned running terminal programmes over SSH, while SSH is also capable of running whole applications on a remote machine and using the GUI locally using `X Forwarding`.

To set up you need to enable X Forwarding in your SSH Servers configuration, add the following to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

and restart the daemon. Once enabled you can run the following on your local machine:

```
ssh -X user@remote-machine matlab
```

and you should then be able to locally use the matlab interface while all being executed on the remote machine.

Another Solution: VNC.

Comment: Thanks for teh answer and what if I need to execute a jar file. What is the command?

Comment: It should work just the same as a normal remotely executed programme. `ssh -X user@remote-machine java filename.jar`.